# what are Magento products tables

Tags: database, magento, import

I have imported a database from 1.4.1 to 1.8 magento store, and it's seems that products doesn't appear in the back-end or in the front-end , But they show in `Catalog > manage categories.`

I need to know which table magento grabs his products informations and displays them in Catalog > manage products, i mean is there any other table or "thing" that grabs products info from besides the table catalog_product_entity ? Is there a column that need to be filled to prevent this issue.

Comment: Try rebuilding the indexes: System->Index management.

Comment: where do you see products on "manage categories"? in "category products" section?

Comment: I can see them in "Category Products"

Answer (score 0):

I did transfered products from 1.7 to 1.8 recently.

1) Transfer all catalog_product_entity_* entities.

2) Also the catalog_category_product, catalog_category_product_index (which holds the associations between products and categories).

When i did that no product appeared in frontend. Then:

3) Check if all products are assigned to current web site id.

So the product tables are the catalog_product_entity_* tables.

In my case i did not transfered the whole database. Try to import only those EAV entities of catalog_product_entity_*.